# 3 TextView's with ellipsize="middle"

Tags: android, textview

I want to have a linearlayout with 3 text views.
Text 1: abcdefghijklmn
Text 2: -
Text 3: nmlkjihgfedcba

It should look like:

```
/-----------------------\
| abc...lmn - nml...cba |
\-----------------------/
```

when text 1 is shorter, "abc", then it should look like this:

```
/-----------------------\
| abc - nmlkji...fedcba |
\-----------------------/
```

I'm not able to get it working. Used weight, but then the "-" stays always in the middle.
Any idea?

Comment: See my current (best) code: pastebin.com/UAmGq5if for the full code, and imagepaste.nullnetwork.net/viewimage.php?id=2934 for the image. But still it's not working, here the first one isn't ellipse'd

Answer (score 0):

This should work. `weight` is exactly the thing you should NOT use here. Unless I am missing something obvious here!

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abcdefghijklmn"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:text="-"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="nmlkjihgfedcba"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't meet my requirements, as it will wrap the text. At least I need to use ellipsize="middle".
See: http://pastebin.com/UAmGq5if for the full code, and http://imagepaste.nullnetwork.net/viewimage.php?id=2934 for the image